# Capture PID of command and use later inside makefile rule

Tags: makefile, sh, gnu-make, pid

I am struggling to find an elegant way of doing the following:

I want a makefile rule which:

- Runs QEMU with certain args, this generates a trace file `trace-XXXXX` where `XXXXX` is the PID of QEMU when it ran.
- Captures this PID when qemu is invoked, ie `./qemu ... & echo $!` and put this in some variable (where the scope of the variable is within the rule)
- Waits for QEMU to finish and then runs a script on the output trace file

Currently I have the following:

```
trace: 
    ./qemu/build/qemu-riscv64 -d plugin,nochain --trace "exec_tb" -plugin ./test_plugin.so ./test_qemu & export TRACE_PID=$$!; \
    echo Trace PID is $$TRACE_PID; \
    wait $$TRACE_PID; \ 
    python3 ./qemu/scripts/simpletrace.py ./qemu/build/trace/trace-events-all trace-$$TRACE_PID
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I see the "Trace PID is " but then get a command not found on `line 1` which I think could be due to the stdout of qemu breaking things.

Is there a clean and elegant way to do this?

Comment: The error message should not be _only_ "command not found", but it should explicitly menstion, which command hasn't been found. The only command in the code you posted, which is looked up via the PATH and hence could produce the error message, is `python3`, and perhaps `exec_tb`, but in theory, your Python scripts could also invoke external commands via PATH.

Comment: I just see `/bin/sh: line 1:  : command not found` .

If I put the command `python3` at the top of the rule then I can enter a python interpreter, so make should be able to find it in PATH

Comment: Well, this already tells us that this is not executed by _bash_. So while the difference perhaps does not matter, I would replace the _bash_ tag in your question with a _sh_ tag, just to clarify it.  Then, the two spaces between the colons would suggest to me, that somewhere, a white space is executed as a command.  Where in this whole execution are you running a sh-script?

Comment: I had thought that make was running the commands in a `sh` shell, so that was where it was coming from.

Comment: In my terminal I can run `./qemu/build/qemu-riscv64 -d plugin,nochain --trace "exec_tb" -plugin ./test_plugin.so ./test_qemu & export TRACE_PID=$!; wait $TRACE_PID; python3 ./qemu/scripts/simpletrace.py ./qemu/build/trace/trace-events-all trace-$TRACE_PID` as a single command successfully, but pasting this into the makefile rule generates an error `File "<fstring>", line 1
    (pid=)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I will try and work out the difference

Comment: (I changed the $ -> $$ in the makefile)

Comment: Did you check, that the lines in your make file start with a physical tab, which is **not** followed by a white space? From a practical viewpoint, I would follow a different approach: Put the complete multi-line command into a script file (bash or sh or whatever), and execute this script from the makefile. The more you decouple make rules from shell code, the easier it is to debug.

Comment: Thank you I will try that now. 

The fstring error seems to happen when python is called from a sh/bash script so I will debug there . Once I do get this working, I am still unsure how to break up the large chained command to make the Makefile more readable.

Comment: Why don't you like my suggestion putting it into a tiny 5-line-script?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought you meant put it in a script to debug (which I've done, thanks! ) and then move it back to the makefile afterwards. Happy to call a script from the makefile but I do feel like it should be possible to elegantly do what I want from within make. I'm still academically interested in that.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: Putting everything together into one file makes it easier to see in one glance, what is going on; but mixing two languages (here: Make and Shell) is always a potential source of error, and I find it easier to maintain code, if I have only one language in one text file.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right, as soon as stuff gets into make it seems to get ugly and confusing

Comment: I can break up my comand with `;` and `/` in the makefile and get the same behaviour as a the script now, just uglier

Comment: It's up to you. I just told you what **I** would do in this case. Of course you are free to choose a different path.

Comment: Running things in the background inside `make` is inherently thorny. I would suggest you encapsulate this inside a script.

Comment: The error message in your comment comes from Python; we obviously cannot see what's inside your Python script.

Comment: One thing I don't understand in your script: You run a program in the background, then do an `echo` and then wait for the background process to finish. Aside from the `echo`, there is no parallelism going on. Why don't you run the script in the foreground instead?

Comment: This is just a method I had seen for capturing the PID. $! will give the PID of the last thing executed in the background

Comment: Always keen to know better ways !

Comment: Yes the reason for the error was that make was using a different (older) version of python. It was confusing me because it didnt happen in my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Captures this PID when qemu is invoked, ie `./qemu ... & echo $!`

The `&` causes your `qemu` to run in the background, but this is counter-productive because you want to wait for it to complete.

The only real reason to capture the PID seems to be to compute the name of the trace file.  If qemu supports it, the best approach would be to choose the name for the trace file yourself, and tell `qemu` to write there.  Then you could just run `qemu` in the foreground (no `wait`), and analyze the file afterward.  The `mktemp` command would serve to create a new file with a distinct name, if you need that.

If you have no way to control the trace file name up front, then you could still do a little better (IMO) by keeping everything in the foreground, something like this:

```
trace: 
        TRACE_PID=$$(/bin/sh -c 'echo $$$$; exec ./qemu/build/qemu-riscv64 -d plugin,nochain --trace "exec_tb" -plugin ./test_plugin.so ./test_qemu >qemu.out 2>&1'); \
        echo Trace PID is $$TRACE_PID; \
        python3 ./qemu/scripts/simpletrace.py ./qemu/build/trace/trace-events-all trace-$$TRACE_PID
```

Notes:

- the shell will execute the contents of the command substitution `$(...)` in a *subshell*, but that's not necessarily running in a different process.  We do want a different process for this, so from the subshell we start a separate shell process.
- the shell running in that separate process reports its PID via an `echo` command, which the top-level shell will capture.  It uses `exec` to run `qemu` *in the same process*, so the PID already reported will be correct for `qemu`.
- The `qemu` command's standard output is redirected to a file to prevent it being captured, too.  Its standard error is redirected to the same file for tidiness, and a bit to avoid potential confusion.
- There is no need to `wait` for anything because no background jobs have been started.  The `echo Trace PID ...` command does not start until after `qemu` has finished.
- There does not appear to be a need to `export TRACE_PID`, as it appears only to be used in the current shell process, not in any child processes.
- Neither this version nor yours responds to a `qemu` failure.  This version could more easily be adapted to do that, and probably should be so adapted.
- You might want to provide a full path to the `python3` executable.  You might even want to create a `make` variable for it.